# How to correctly parse arrays when using Azure CLI commands with Powershell variables

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

Powershell Version: 5.1.22621.1778
Azure CLI Version: 2.53.0

I am using the Azure CLI to execute commands in a cloud subscription.
My issue is that I want to assign the JSON result to a PowerShell variable.

When I do this for an array result, the PowerShell variable contains a string array, line by line, of the cli result, e.g.

`$result = az group list -o json"`

Returns:

`[ { "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/group1", "location": "xxx", "managedBy": null, "name": "group1", "properties": { "provisioningState": "Succeeded" }, "tags": {}, "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups" } ]`

I would expect that $result contain an array of resource groups, if 1 group is returned like the example above, then:

$result.count should equal 1

However, in this case $result.count == 13
Furthermore, $result.GetType() == System.Array

It appears that $result is an array of the string lines returned, rather than a JSON array of the data.

I have a work around, that seems like a bit of hack:
`$result = (az group list -o json | out-string) $groupList = ConvertTo-Json ($result)`

Basically, convert the result to a string and then convert it back into JSON.

Anyone know a better way or why this is happening?

Comment: Yeah its a much cleaner solution, still not sure why the conversion is needed though, cheers

Comment: The output from `az group` is a JSON string, so you need to use `ConvertFrom-Json` to convert the JSON string to a PS object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.3):

```
$groupList=$(az group list -o json | ConvertFrom-Json)
```